# css - background position (with slight padding?)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to emulate something like

```
 background-position: left center
```

With the exception that it is not actually flush with the left side, so like 5-10 px off the left side and center.

My first attempt was like so

```
 background-position: left 5px center
```

CSS does not seem to like that though, is something like this possible without messing with margins?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't append the '5px' - replace 'left' with the number of pixels to offset.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible yes, and there are several ways.

and W3C have explained it pretty good over here (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Scroll to the table of Property Values and read the description of the X and Y values or the Xpos and Ypos values.

in your case, I believe that it will be something like:

```
background-position: 5px center;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Ah, can't believe i missed that. Thank you!!